# Assign a javascript variable to a ruby variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a score counter and I'm trying to assign the value of that score counter to a ruby variable, and then have that variable be saved.

View:

```
        var score = 0;
        window.setInterval(
        function countscore() {
            if($('#game-area').is(':animated')){
                score = score + 1;
                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
                document.getElementById("score").submit(); //trying to assign here
            }

        }, 100);
```

controller:

```
def index
    @user = User.find(current_user)     
    @score = @user.score
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do something more complicated than that. The ERB code generates an HTML file that gets sent to the client, which has no idea what server software is sending it the HTML file, so it can't assign a server-side variable. You have to upload the value to the server in some way. For example, you could use a form submission, URL querystring parameters, or an AJAX request.

Comment: I edited my code to add a form submission but how would I then assign the javascript variable to the ruby variable @csander

Comment: @nums11 You don't. Ruby code is executed on the server before anything is sent to the client. Once you're on the client the only way you can do anything Ruby-related is by making a request to the server (e.g., Ajax, Websockets, etc.)

Comment: So what you're saying is even after the form submission I still have to make an ajax request? @DaveNewton

Comment: @nums11 If you're submitting a form using normal means then you already *have* the variable in `params` and you can do whatever you want with it. It's really not clear what the issue is. You can't just have a "JavaScript variable" magically sent to the server in a form, it needs to be a form field.

Comment: The thing is I can't necessarily have a form because the score of the user is not something that is manually inputted. @DaveNewton

Comment: @nums11 That's irrelevant. What exactly are you calling `submit()` on then?! You might want to take a step back and figure out some bigger-picture basics before going much further; there's a huge difference between a JavaScript variable and a DOM element.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
var score = '<%= @user.score %>'
```

Comment: This is the wrong way. He wants JS to Ruby, not Ruby to JS. Hence it's Client to Server which will need some sort of HTTP call.